# Numbers $k>1$ for which $3^{k-1}+1$ is a multiplicative unit modulo $k$

Tags: number-theory

Is there a way to say when a number $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k>1$ has the property that $3^{k-1}+1$ is in the multiplicative group $(\mathbb{Z}/k\mathbb{Z})^*$ ?

Answer (score 1):

We are looking for integers $k>1$ with $gcd(3^{k-1}+1,k)=1$. Clearly $k$ has to be odd, because otherwise both numbers are even, so that its gcd is divisible by $2$. For odd primes $k$ we have $3^{k-1}\equiv 1 \bmod k$ so that $gcd(3^{k-1}+1,k)=1$. Now try to extend this to all odd $k>1$.